# Why is WPF progressbar incrementing by bits and not fluent?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a WPF ProgressBar where I set the Min and Max values. I then update the value using a DispatcherTimer. I also made a label which is bound to the same value as the value which is going into the ProgressBar. The label is updating fluently (every millisecond). The progressbar however, only changes small blocks at a time. What is going on and how can I make the incrementing fluent?

Updated: Code request:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding XPath=@End}"
    Value="{Binding XPath=@Position}" Style="{StaticResource ProgressStyle}" />
```

...

```
DispatcherTimer DTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
DTimer.Tick += (s, args) =>
{  
    var currentposition = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetPosition(stream);
}  
DTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
DTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Show us your code.  Also, updating every millisecond is pointless, given that that is faster than the monitor's refresh rate.

Comment: Would you mind to post some code?

Comment: The default animation speed is 60 frames per second.

Comment: I also update other stuff in the timer which depend on the millisecond resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it asynchronously. Try using the `Dispatcher` object to do something like this:

```
public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```

...

```
RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
{
    currentposition = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetPosition(stream);
});
```

Of course, how smooth the `ProgressBar` will update will depend on the values that you return from your method. If you return a value that is simply incremented by one each time, then I can't see any other reason why it shouldn't update smoothly.